# How to use react-native-swiper

Tags: react-native

native-swiper` in order to render a swiper of users profile. Currently I managed to render a swiper but it's getting me the first element of my data everytime and not the element where I've clicked. Here is the code :

```
export default data = [
   {
      id:1,
      name:"Anastasia",
      photo_path: "https://www.one-voyance.fr/media/cache/slider/images/voyants/anastasia/anastasia.jpg",
      age: "23",
      pratique: "Trans.",
      distance: "200m",
      connected: 1,
      description:"Anastasia, medium pure sans support.Mon don héréditaire me vient de mes grands parents. Prête à vous servir, je m’appuie de mes guides pour vous guider dans votre chemin de vie.Je suis compétente dans tous les domaines. La vie est faite de détours, en connaitre les recoins permet d’avancer sereinement sans se poser de questions. Je vous attends pour une voyance claire et de qualité.",
      //numero:"06 01 02 03 04"
      principale:"Principale",
      localisation:"Saint Germain en Laye (91)"
   },
   {
      id:2,
      name:"Angélique",
      photo_path:"https://www.one-voyance.fr/media/cache/slider/images/voyants/angelique/angelique.jpg",
      age: "28",
      pratique: "Homme",
      distance: "600m",
      connected: 1,
      description:"Je suis votre voyante Angélique, médium pure ainsi que shaman.N’hésitez pas à m’appeler. Je suis prête à vous dévoiler votre futur. Ma voyance est sans complaisance. Tous les détails sont évoqués et je parle de tous les domaines. Je m’appuie sur mes flash pour vous aider dans les hauts et les bas, vos déconvenues et vos heureux moments.Ma tâche est de vous indiquer la route à suivre, celle vers le succès en évitant les embûches de l'existence.",
      //numero:"06 66 55 88 99"
      principale:"Principale",
      localisation:"Saint Germain en Laye (91)"
   }
]
```

```
render () {
    return (
        <Swiper showsPagination={false}>
          {this.state.items.map((item, key) => {
            return (
                <ScrollView key={key} style = {styles.view_container}>
                    <View style={styles.photo}>
                      <ImageBackground source={{uri:item.photo_path}} style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
                        <View style={styles.photo_content}>
                          <LinearGradient colors={['transparent', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)']} style={{ position: 'absolute', left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, height: 80 }} />
                          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                            <View>
                              <Text style={{ fontSize: 40, color:'white' }}>{item.age}</Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ marginRight: 7, marginLeft: 7, backgroundColor: '#ffffff', width: 1, height: 39 }}></View>
                              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', flex:1 }}>
                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                                  <View style={[styles.bulle_presence, { backgroundColor: colorConnected } ]}></View>
                                  <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, fontWeight: '600', color:'white' }}>{item.name}</Text>
                                </View>
                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                                  <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, color:'white' }}>{item.distance}</Text>
                                  <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, color:'white'}}>{item.pratique}</Text>
                                </View>
                              </View>
                          </View>
                        </View>

               </ImageBackground>
</View>
</ScrollView>
</Swiper>
```

So this code is getting me a swiper but with the first id of my data everytime, it doesn't get me the swiper with the id of the user where I clicked.

Comment: Can you put a screenshot OR gif of the UI?

Comment: No I can't sorry, but it's just a flatlist with 2 column and when I click on one item, it should render me in an another view a swiper with the info of the item clicked.

Comment: Do you want to render which item clicked on the same screen "that contains the FlatList"?

Comment: No I want to render it in another screen. Let's say my flatlist in Home.js, I want to display the swiper in Profile.js

Comment: Well, so you can create another screen and in flatList screen add a function when item pressed that's will navigate you to profile screen and pass a params if you want to use them in profile screen `this.props.navigation.navigate("profile",{ id: item.id, name:item.name ,etc..})`

Comment: Yes that's what I've done, but how can I pass this params in the swiper ? So it will display the one clicked and the previous and next ?